# Used brew to install node, when checking node version, says not installed

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I have tried uninstalling `node` with `brew` and reinstalling. I get a link error and when I check what version of node I have installed with `node -v`, it says node is not installed. What could be going on?

Comment: Do not use brew. NVM is the best tool to install and use different versions of NodeJs in local mac, ubuntu and Windows systems

Comment: Please show the exact command you’ve used as well as their output.